# extract info from another web page 3

Tags: php

I have this test.php where i have this info :

```
callername1 : "Fernando Verdasco1"
callername2 : "Fernando Verdasco2"
callername3 : "Fernando Verdasco3"
callername4 : "Fernando Verdasco4"
callername5 : "Fernando Verdasco5"
```

this page automatically changes that  name every 10 min

In this another page test1.php

I need a php code that takes only the name of the callername3 and echo'it

```
Fernando Verdasco3
```

I've tried this like so test1.php

```
<?php 
    $Text=file_get_contents("test.php");
    preg_match('/callername3\s*:\s*\'([^\']+)\'/',$Text,$Match); 
    echo $Match[1] ."\n";
    ?>
```

but no result.

If the list is this way thei work

```
callername1 : 'Fernando Verdasco1'
callername2 : 'Fernando Verdasco2'
callername3 : 'Fernando Verdasco3'
callername4 : 'Fernando Verdasco4'
callername5 : 'Fernando Verdasco5'
```

Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your regular expression to respect double quotes (") rather than single quotes, like

```
preg_match('/callername3\s*:\s*\"([^\"]+)\"/',$Text,$Match);
```